# Como pegar a URL final de um redirecionamento por JS?

Tags: python, redirecionamento, redirect

Estava tentando fazer um código para pegar o url final de redirecionamento de alguns links, consegui fazer para a maioria dos links que precisava, entranto para este não consegui: https://redir.lomadee.com/v2/987163d4

TOdos os outros links funcionaram com urllib2 or requests.

```
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(lili[i], headers=headers)
    if lili[i] != r.url:
        print i, r.url
```

ou

```
    response = urllib2.urlopen(lili[i])
    if lili[i] != response.geturl():
        print i, response.geturl()
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isto? Não gostaria de usar o Selenium para isso, não é viável (muito demorado).

Answer (score 3):

Curiosa esta estratégia neste tipo de serviços, é muito bem jogado para evitar precisamente o que queres fazer.

O que se passa é o seguinte. Parece, mas não é um redicionamento (codigo 301), ou seja, ao analizar o corpo da resposta consegui ver (por sorte) o que se passava:

```
setTimeout(location.href='https://www.walmart.com.br/dvd-automotivo-pioneer-avh-3880-com-usb-frontal-e-tela-de-7/3820066/pr?utm_term=22696088&utm_campaign=lomadee&utm_medium=afiliados&utm_source=lomadee&lmdsid='+new Date().getTime().toString().slice(8,12)+'29157007', 500);
```

Ora isto é um redirecionamento mas que só é delegado após a página já estar deste lado (lado cliente) e o javascript ser interpretado, daí com requests não conseguires ver este a ser realizado, isto serve para "garantir" que o pedido foi feito a partir de um *browser*.

Aqui tens um *workaround* para conseguires o url, neste serviço específico, para onde vai a seguir com requests (com urllib2 seria a mesma coisa):

```
import requests, re

req = requests.get('https://redir.lomadee.com/v2/987163d4')
redi_url = re.findall('(?<=location.href=["\'])https?://.+?(?=["\'])', req.text)

if redi_url:
    print(redi_url[0]) # https://www.walmart.com.br/dvd-automotivo-pioneer-avh-3880-com-usb-frontal-e-tela-de-7/3820066/pr?utm_term=22696088&utm_campaign=lomadee&utm_medium=afiliados&utm_source=lomadee&lmdsid=
```

Aqui acredito que algum(s) dos colegas que tenha mais jeito para expressões regulares me consiga ajudar, neste contexto não parece ser a melhor maneira de usar regex ([corpo total da resposta aqui](https://pastebin.com/uLUm5hJd), o `setTimeout` que redireciona está mesmo fim), e que estejam à vontade para editar a resposta.

Comment: Basicamente é isso mesmo (mas só vai funcionar para este serviço específico). E em outras situações, a informação do link estará em contextos diferentes. Para ter compatibilidade com vários redirecionadores, só com algum engine que execute o JS de fato, ou implementando um crawler para cada fornecedor (um para o lomadee, outro para o redirecionador X, etc) e ainda tem que ficar atualizando sempre que for detectado um caso onde o link não seja encontrado (que é sinal que determinado redirecionador mudou a estrutura da página).

Comment: @Bacco exato, daria uma solução com selenium + phantomJS mas o AP sublinhou que não queria optar por essa solução. Apesar de assim ser volátil e só ter a certeza que funciona para este url de origem

Comment: Espero que o autor da pergunta esteja fazendo isto justamente para eliminar intermediadores de links curtos. Fica a sugestão para ele de além de remover o intermediador, remover os dados de rastreamento do link final, senão simplesmente ele estará "eternizando" o ID de parceiro de quem intermediou. (eu faço isso nos meus sistemas, sempre que possivel removo tudo que é de analytics, como `?utm=` e mais uma série, de todos os links que eu processo.

Comment: @Bacco sim, a partir daqui seria só eliminar do `redi_url` o que está depois do "?", um split bastaria

Comment: @Bacco Isso mesmo, eu faço o filtro dos utm_ que aparecem nesses links, entranto é difícil de prever pois ele variam de site para site.
Miguel, infelizmente não é tão simples quanto dar um split no question mark, pois isso pode levar embora alguns parâmetros que ficam após ele, como por exemplo parâmetros de busca no site. Se alguém tiver alguma dica? Para eliminar somente os parâmetros que setam cookies de parceiros, gostaria de saber mais sobre :)

Comment: @leo04 teria que ser caso a caso mesmo. Uma tabelinha relacionando URL de origem com o código de captura do url, ai ja aproveita e remove o especifico de cada um, já que tem que customizar o código mesmo. O chato é que tem que ficar dando manutenção depois. O melhor mesmo é um treco que te avise quando não achou a informação, pois ai vc tem como "consertar rápido"

Comment: Eu tenho alguns serviços que infelizmente dependem de crawler, pq a anta que fez o site de origem nao pos API, entao alem de capturar o que eu preciso, eu ponho código para me alertar quando algo está anormal estruturalmente. Ai pelo menos quando alguma das fontes muda o código, eu fico sabendo em tempo. Detalhe relevante: não se trata de consumo indevido, muito pelo contrário, meus crawlers são muito mais leves que uma consulta manual, que carrega um monte de coisa a mais (e que o usuário final ia ter que acessar de qualquer forma).

Comment: @leo04 como seria o retorno ideal do url neste caso (quais o parametros que precisas/não precisas manter)? que eu tento ajustar a resposta. Tem em mente que só vai funcionar para este redirecionador, mas é viável enquanto não for mudada a estrutura do mesmo